# I’m omitting that I’m married to an American man in my fiancée visa application to the UK. Will this be a problem? Do they cross-reference databases?

Tags: visas, usa, uk, visa-refusals, airport-security

I’m omitting that I’m married to a American man in my fiancée visa application to the UK. Will this be a problem? Do they cross-reference databases? Is there a chance this will pass trough?

Comment: Well, if you get caught eventually, you will be committing multiple crimes across two countries (bigamy and perjury, to name a few). I recommend that you don't do this if you don't enjoy time in jail :(

Comment: Immigration authorities react very badly to misrepresentation (aka lying)  on visa applications, even if it's a lie by omission. If they do find out you can expect your application to be refused and a lengthy ban. If they find out after you've entered Britain they can cancel your visa and remove you. This is a seriously bad idea, even without the other criminal considerations.

Comment: @InsanityRules I doubt this is a lie by omission. Surely a marriage visa application includes a statement that the applicant is eligible to marry, and being already married makes OP ineligible.

Comment: @HelloItIsMe Your question implies that you are planning to marry bigamously in the U.K. if your visa application is approved. Are you expecting to be free to marry during your visit? If so, why not postpone it until you are?

Comment: Why not get a final divorce first, and then complete the visa application truthfully?

Comment: On the database matching, it is not just a matter of whether they will find out and ban you for deception on this application. You could get caught several years in the future.

Comment: Don't know why this question is voted down. The question is absolutely fine. The intended action isn't, but votes should be about the question itself.

Comment: If you ever travelled/had a visa as a married person (not just to the uk), changed your name (had a passport in your married name), etc, there is a chance they will have access to that info

Comment: Are you in the process of divorcing the American man?

Answer (score 6):

> Do they cross-reference databases?

The first question is whether or not the US federal government even knows about your marriage. If you've never applied for a spouse visa to the US or otherwise notified the federal government about your situation (such as through a joint tax return), it's possible that there isn't a record of your marriage in any federal databases. If there is in fact a record, the UK could probably look it up without much fuss thanks to the [Five Eyes agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes).

However the above is absolutely irrelevant: you as a visa applicant should always strive for 100% honesty or avoid applying for a given visa altogether. If the UK ever finds out you've lied on your application you can expect a long ban from the country in the future. The risk is simply not worth the potential time savings - finish up your divorce in the US and then come to the UK without having to lie to anyone.

Answer (score 2):

They won’t need to check any databases. You have to prove that you’re free to marry, typically you’ll need to provide, for example, a sworn affidavit / Declaration of Single Status (no impediment) signed and stamped by a notary public or equivalent in your country of residence.

Comment: OPs country of residence is probably not the US.  Foreign authorities won't necessarily have to know about the marriage.

Comment: @JonathanReez Agree, documentary evidence from both her home country and her country of residence.

Comment: Her home country might not be aware either. Heck, even the US federal government might not be aware if OP never applied for a spouse visa to the US.

Comment: @JonathanReez Good point. Let’s hope her U.K. fiancé is aware